# CROSS APPLY getting the most recent date

Tags: sql-server

Currently my query is returning three records. The reason for this is that the CRT_STAT table has found 3 matching records. I would like to get the record that has the most recent date. My `CRT_STAT` table has a column called `DISPOSITION_DATE`.

I need to add a date check in this part of the query where it selects the most recent date of the group of records it finds (in this case three).

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.CRT_STAT as crtStat
    WHERE crtStat.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN 
    AND crtSTat.DISPOSITION_DATE ='DATE IS MOST RECENT OF THE THREE RECORDS FOUND'

) crtStat
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY DISPOSITION_DATE DESC`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use order by with top 1:

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT top 1 *
    FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.CRT_STAT as crtStat
    WHERE crtStat.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN 
    order by crtSTat.DISPOSITION_DATE desc
) crtStat
```

This will return the latest record. If you're already fetching the data from CRT_STAT you could also use row number with DISPOSITION_DATE without having to use a cross apply.

Comment: Dude thats so clever. I was selecting the TOP 1 before but it wasnt giving me the record I needed. You are the real MVP. Thanks